# Question about nonisomorphic polynomial rings.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, terminology, abstract-algebra

Let $n,k > 1$ be positive integers.
Define the reduced polynomial rings :

$g^k_n = \Bbb R[X_n]/(G^k_n(X_n))$ where $G^k_n$ is a real polynomial of degree $n$ (that keeps the ring reduced).
(k is just an index , not a power or such)

The question is how many nonisomorphic reduced polynomial rings of degree $n$ are there ?
Lets call that $f(n)$.

With nonisomorphic I mean that the elements of the rings (between any 2 rings) are not linearly dependant.

For instance $ \Bbb R[X]/((X)^3-1)$ and $ \Bbb R[Y]/((Y)^3+1)$ are not linearly dependant and thus nonisomorphic.
(one of those 2 rings is algebraicly closed , while the other is not hence they cannot be linearly dependant)

Is $f(n)=n$ ?

Im not sure if isomorphic is the correct terminology for what I want.
If not, what is ? And is it still a kind of morphism ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $X^3-1=(X-1)(X^2+X+1)$ and $Y^3+1=(Y+1)(Y^2-Y+1)$ are reducible.

Comment: Also, it is not clear to me what you mean by *"elements of the rings (between any $2$ rings) are not linearly dependent."*. The word *'nonisomorphic'* already has a very clear meaning.

Comment: And what is the role of the integer $k$ in this question?

Comment: I edited the question.
I hope it is better now. I added my doubts about the use of the word " isomorphism " and removed the silly restriction on the polynomial $G^k_n$ that it should be irreducible.

Comment: Neither $\Bbb{R}[X]/(X^3-1)$ or $\Bbb{R}[Y]/(Y^3+1)$ is algebraically closed; they aren't even fields. Moreover they *are* isomorphic as rings, by the map given by $X\ \longmapsto\ -Y$. So what do you mean by 'nonisomorphic' and 'linearly dependent'?

Comment: And it is still not clear to me what the role of $k$ is in this whole question.

Comment: This is a train wreck, wow.

Comment: Why do I get 4 downvotes ? Im new to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any polynomial $f\in\Bbb{R}[X]$ with $\deg(f)>2$ is reducible over $\Bbb{R}$, so there are no reduced polynomial rings of degree $n>2$. If $\deg(f)=2$ and $f$ is irreducible, then we have $\Bbb{R}[X]/(f)\cong\Bbb{C}$. Hence there is only one reduced polynomial ring of degree $2$, up to isomorphism, and there are no reduced polynomial rings of degree $n$ for $n>2$. Put differently, we have
$$f(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1&\text{ if }n=2\\0&\text{ if }n>2\end{array}\right..$$

**EDIT:** As the question has been modified, I'll add another answer:

The quotient $\Bbb{R}[X_n]/(G_n(X_n))$ is reduced if and only if $G_n(X_n)$ is a product of distinct irreducible factors. Suppose $P_1,\ldots,P_m\in\Bbb{R}[X_n]$ are distinct irreducible polynomials such that $$G_n(X_n)=\prod_{i=1}^mP_i(X_n),$$
then by the Chinese remainder theorem we have
$$\Bbb{R}[X_n]/(G_n(X_n))\cong\prod_{i=1}^m\Bbb{R}[X_n]/(P_i(X_n))\cong\Bbb{R}^r\times\Bbb{C}^s,$$
where $r$ and $s$ are the numbers of linear resp. quadratic irreducible factors of $G_n$. Hence the number $f(n)$ of non-isomorphic reduced polynomial rings of degree $n$ is precisely the number of ways we can write $n=r+2s$ with $r,s\in\Bbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, which is precisely $\lfloor\tfrac{n}{2}\rfloor+1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im sorry I made an awful mistake.
I edited the question.
I hope it is better now. I added my doubts about the use of the word " isomorphism " and removed the silly restriction on the polynomial $G^k_n$ that it should be irreducible.
Maybe you can take a look at it again now ?
Thanks.